# Увеличить скорость парсинга

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

как можно увеличить скорость парсинга, чтобы он мог выполнять около 4000 запросов в минуту. Как это можно реализовать?

Код:

```
string[] pair1 = searchText.Split();

                  foreach (var pair in pair1)
                  {
                      var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
                      var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                      string url = $" + {pair}";
                      htmlDoc.LoadHtml(web.Load(url).Text);

                      var content = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='']").InnerText;

                      richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                      {
                          richTextBox2.Text += string.Join(string.Empty, content.SkipWhile(x => !char.IsDigit(x)).TakeWhile(x => char.IsWhiteSpace(x) || char.IsDigit(x))).Replace(" ", string.Empty) + "\n";    
                      });
                  }
```

Comment: Инициализировать web и htmlDoc вне цикла, для начала. Дальше профилировщик в помощь, смотреть где бутылочное горлышко

Comment: @p-c, а зачем их делать вне цикла? Тогда как он будет получать новую страницу сайта. htmlDoc.LoadHtml(web.Load(url).Text);

Comment: Так и будет получать. Сейчас у вас var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();  var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); создаются на каждой итерации, что не нужно. Их можно содзать один раз вне цикла и дальше работать с инициализрованными класами.

Comment: Что показывает профилировщик? У меня есть подозрения, что парсинг -- вещь небыстрая и для нужной производительности нужно будет уходить от последовательной обработки запросов. У вас процесс обработки страниц не зависит один от другого?

Comment: @AK там еще используется библиотека которая ищет по DOM, возможно (но не точно) поиск по тексту или регулярка будет быстрее.

Comment: @Den2908 Инициализацию нужно делать до цикла чтобы соединение с сервером не рвалось и не инициализировалось при каждой итерации цикла. Если и этого мало будет, то уже смотреть в сторону асинхронности и мультипоточности.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Как сейчас сейчас занимаюсь вопросом многопоточности.